# How get MailSeverConnect to resolve host?

Tags: internet, email

I've tried without success to get `MailServerConnect` to work, in the first instance, with Gmail.

Method 1: In Mathematica's Preferences > Internet and Mail > Incoming, i specified mail.gmail.com as Server, my username on Gmail as Username, entered my paswword there, and saved. Yet

```
MailServerConnect[]
```

gives error "Could not resolve host: mail.gmail.com".

Method 3: Evaluating

```
MailServerConnect[MailSettings -> 
    <|"IncomingMailServer" -> <|"Host" -> "mail.gmail.com", 
      "Username" -> "myusernamehere"|>|>]
```

followed by entering my Gmail password at the pop-up prompt, gives the same error.

What's wrong?

Comment: For Gmail the host is `imap.gmail.com`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: Are you sure about that? Because if I use it, I get a different error message now from `MailServerConnect`: Login denied. (When specifying my Mail Settings in Mathematica's Preferences, do I include the `@gmail.com` as part of my username? (I've tried it both with and without, and still same error from `MailServerConnect`.)

Comment: Hi @murray, I ran into the same issue, and the only workaround I could find was to change the security settings on my GMail account. The reason / instructions are described [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). It would be nice if WL used the 'stronger security measures' referred to in that link. For username, I include the `@gmail.com` part.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: Thanks for that tip!

Comment: Does anyone know the host for `Hotmail`?